# Socket.isConnected() make my android app force close

Tags: android, sockets

I don't know what happen with my source code about Socket in Android, when I use method

> .isConnected()

My app always force close. And here my source code

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private String IP;
    private int PORT;
    private Socket socket;
    private PrintWriter printWriter;
    private TextView text;

    private EditText fieldIp;
    private EditText fieldPort;


    private Button connect;
    private FrameLayout frameIP;

    private String message;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        frameIP = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.frameIP);
        connect = (Button)findViewById(R.id.connect);
        fieldIp = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ip);
        fieldPort = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.port);
        text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.keterangan);
        connect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                IP = fieldIp.getText().toString();
                PORT = Integer.parseInt(fieldPort.getText().toString());
                SocketConnect socketConnect = new SocketConnect(IP,PORT);
                socketConnect.execute();
            }
        });
    }


    private class SocketConnect extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

        String ip;
        int port;

        public SocketConnect(String a, int b){
            this.ip = a;
            this.port = b;
        }


        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                socket = new Socket();
                socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(ip,port));
                if(socket.isConnected())
                {
                    text.setText("Connected!");
                }
                else
                {
                    text.setText("Failed to connect!");
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("MyActivity",e.getMessage());
            }
            finally {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ListViewText.class));
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

And I use this in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

I hope you can help me guys :(

Comment: Can you post your logcat stacktrace?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this) ... but it is pretty obvious that, in fact, it is yet another NOMTE question

Comment: @Selvin : No. This isn't a NOMTE issue - there's nothing in the OP's code which shows any network operations on the main thread. It's actually the other way around - the thread running `doInBackground` is attempting to modify the text in a `TextView`.

Comment: This problem has exactly nothing to do with the `isConnected()` method, as a little more investigation on your part would have disclosed. You don't even have to call it at all here: see my comment under @Squonk's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `doInBackground` method as follows...

```
@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {

    boolean success = true;

    try {
        socket = new Socket();
        socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(ip, port));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        success = false;
        Log.e("MyActivity", e.getMessage());
    }
    return success;
}
```

Then add an `onPostExecute` method...

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(boolean result) {
    if(result) {
        text.setText("Connected!");
        startActivity(new Intent(MyActivity.this, ListViewText.class));
    }
    else {
        text.setText("Failed to connect!");
    }
}
```

Comment: The `isConnected()` call is completely pointless here. It cannot possibly return false at the point you are calling it. You just called `connect():` there was no exception; *ergo* it is connected. If you don't enter the exception handler, setup to display 'success': if you do enter the exception handler, setup to display 'failure'.

Comment: @EJP : Valid point. I'll admit it's been a while since I worked with `Sockets` and I was just working with the OP's code.

Comment: It works guys, thanks @Squonk and all who have answered my question. Do you have any blog as my reference to learn socket android?

Answer (score 1):

First thing you are calling UI operation outside of UI thread (that is why AsyncTask was created, to handle background job only in `doInBackground`) So  problem about displaying text un TextView is solved...

But more important thing:

Never open Socket in AsyncTask. On [Android developer site](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) you can find following:

> If you need to keep threads running for long periods of time, it is
>   highly recommended you use the various APIs provided by the
>   java.util.concurrent package such as Executor, ThreadPoolExecutor and
>   FutureTask.)

And that is exactly what you want to do. So use [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html), [Thread](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html) or those mentioned above instead.