# Use Socket in another activity Android

Tags: android, sockets, android-activity

This question relates to my last question in here [Socket.isConnected() make my android app force close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28141717/) and now I can migrate to another `Activity` but I don't know to use the `Socket` that is connected from the previous `Activity`, send and receive response from server too. Please help me guys :(

Comment: Don't do socket work in your activities.  Create a separate class to handle the network activities.  Provide access to the socket via static methods of the class.

Comment: Do you have any reference for me?? Sorry I'm really new here

Comment: developer.android.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have posted answer to your previous question about how to properly connect to Socket because `AsyncTask` is really bas solution, it will eventually terminate if previous `Activity` terminates (I'm not exactly sure when `AsyncTasks` are dying exactly). @ginc0de suggested perfect solution. Study something about Singleton for example... I think this is best solution for your problem.

```
public class ConnectThread extends Thread {

    // singleton Part

    private static ConnectThread instance;

    public static ConnectThread getInstance(){
        return (instance == null) ? instance = new ConnectThread() : instance;
    }

    private ConnectThread(){
    }

    // implementation part
    private Socket mSocket;

    public Socket getSocket() {
        return mSocket;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        mSocket = new Socket();
        // connect etc.
    }
}
```

Firstly you have to call `ConnectThread.getInstance().start()` somewhere (no more than once to start Thread) Then you should obtain Socket anywhere by calling `ConnectThread.getInstance().getSocket()` After completing communication or leaving application (this is hard part, and I really don't think you should handle Socket on multiple Activities) you have to close Thread ([`interrupt()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt%28%29)) and socket in it (override the `interrupt()` method and call [`Socket.close()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html#close%28%29))

Be aware of method [`Activity.runOnUiThread()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) study how interfaces are working (you will have to implement some listeners), don't give up but try to understand basics of Object Oriented Programming (Just in this answer it is Singleton, Interfaces, static variables)

Comment: Wow nice explain guys I've to try that method. Thank you very much.

Comment: The methods should be static since you cannot create an instance of the class as the constructor is private.

Comment: I create one file SocketService.java and give some parameter on my method maybe you can check in here [SocketService.java](https://github.com/ginc0der/socket-service/blob/master/com/example/skripsi/socket/SocketService.java) and you can find main <code>Activity</code> in [here](https://github.com/ginc0der/socket-service/blob/master/com/example/skripsi/MyActivity.java) when I try to connect, the `Toast` as notification for the `Thread` is not alive is appeared and when I try to connect again my application will be force close.

Comment: And in `SocketService.java` you can find `Context` as parameter, that because I wanna try to migrate `Activity` from `SocketService.java` but always fail and make my force close.

Comment: We are not here to solve you school project or what is it :) Accept answer, read Logs and Google a little bit.